# Email from Google - 64bit architecture is missing

Tags: android, react-native

I got an email from Google team thay is saying my app does not have 64bit apk uploaded. I'm already using react-native 0.59.10 and I thought that between 4 generated apks two of them are already 64 bit. Anybody to help?

I'm enclosing the email:

```
Hello Google Play Developer,

By August 1, 2019, all apps that use native code must provide a 64-bit
version in order to publish an update. As of the sending of this email, at
least one of your apps* does not yet meet the requirement:

NAME_OF_THE_APP_OF_MINE

Action required

Please review all of your apps for 64-bit compliance and submit your  
updated apps by August 1, 2019. The Android developers guide provides
step-by-step instructions for assessing the use of native code and becoming
64-bit compliant, including identifying native libraries, building with
64-bit libraries, testing and publishing.

Please note that we are not making changes to our policy on 32-bit support.
Google Play will continue to deliver apps with 32-bit native code to 32-bit
devices. The requirement means that those apps will need to have a 64-bit
version as well.

If you have any questions or concerns, please contact Google Play developer
support.

*Note: This list of apps reflects Google's best estimate as of the sending
of this email. Only the top apps in your account are listed. This list
should not be considered exhaustive. We encourage you to review ALL of your
apps for native code and make sure 64-bit variants are offered where  
necessary. A full list of exemptions to the August 1st deadline can be
found in our blog post.


The Google Play Team Conversation Globe
```

this is from my build.gradle: `include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"` and I uploaded all the apks (without universal apk) to google play console release.

These are generated files, that I've uploaded to Google Play:

[image]

I'm also enclosing an output of build apk analyzer (Android Studio) of arm64-v8a apk file.

[image]

It means that i have no 32bit libs left in my 64bit build or am I wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you read this https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have all your answers here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1288668/Making-sure-your-Android-game-is-ready-for-64-bi-2

Comment: By this tutorial I found that every of my 64bit build contains only 64bit libs. What could went wrong in my case?

Answer (score 0):

> if you are adding a new app to the Play Store, or updating an existing
>   app, you must target API level 26 (Android 8.0) or higher. And as
>   Google outlined in a recent blog post, new applications will be
>   required to have a target API level of 28 (Android 9.0) beginning in
>   August 2019.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/02/expanding-target-api-level-requirements.html

Comment: minSdkVersion = 16 
compileSdkVersion = 28 
targetSdkVersion = 28 ,,, this is my version setup